# Get length of property after destroying element in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

In KnockoutJS you can have a property that is an array of objects. Eg.

`self.items` could be made up of items:

```
var item = function (data){
  //mapping here
}
```

You can then "destroy" one of those objects by calling something like:

```
self.items.destroy(item);
```

But then if I check/bind to the length of self.items, it is still the full length (including destroyed objects). Eg, this won't get updated properly after destroying stuff, and stays visible:

```
data-bind="visible: myData.items().length > 0"
```

**How to get the length, minus the destroyed objects?**

I suppose I could create a `computed` kojsLength method and add it to every object, that loops over the array and counts all items that don't have the `_destroy` property?

But is there a built in KOJS solution, or do I have to do this?

**Edit, my solution:**

For me, since I have no use for the _destroy property on the back end, directly substituting in the `remove` function for `destroy` works perfect.

Comment: Are you using rails at backend? Why don't you just use `remove` (e.g `self.items.remove(item)` ) istead of `destroy`?

Comment: no not using rails, i was thinking maybe I could just use remove actually, will give it a shot

Comment: yes since i have no use for the _destroy property on the back end, directly substituting in "remove" works like a charm... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because destroyed elements are not actually removed from the underlying array. They are just marked as destroyed, as you can see by running the below snippet.

**There is no built-in KO solution for that.**

If you want to exclude them by computing length, you need a custom length function which discards them:

```js
function viewModel(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var array = ko.observableArray([new viewModel("a"), new viewModel("b")]);

console.log(array().length);
array.destroy(array()[0]);
console.log(array().length);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array()));

function lengthOfAlive(obs) {
  var before = obs().length;
  var res = before;
  for (var i = 0; i < before; ++i) {
    if (obs()[i]._destroy)
      res--;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(lengthOfAlive(array));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```